# Regarding price tag

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Can anyone help me to solve this issue,i need to remove price tag from one place
[image: Magento bookstore]

Comment: I have one more issue can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Open: *app/design/frontend/[Your_package]/[Your_Theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml*

**and comment this code**  `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>`

Comment: I dont have this code in view .phtml

Comment: i can forward yoy my view.phtml code

Comment: This issue has been occurred after adding cedcommerce marketplace basic extention

Comment: enable the template hint and check  from where view.phtml  are getting

Comment: Only price tag is coming from price.phtml

Comment: remaing everything from app/design/frontend/[Your_package]/[Your_Theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: price .phtml is locaated in

Comment: and also located in app/design/frontend/base

Comment: app/design/frontend/default

Comment: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml" this is the location, when i delete all data price comment disapper

Comment: Please donot delete codeof price.phtml

Comment: <!--  <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, true) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, true) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span> -->

Comment: i commented this code, but price do not show

Comment: i want a single price block to be displayed

Comment: thanks buddy, i have sought out my issue, for your refrence please read this step

Answer (score 0):

1) Open ***app/design/frontend/default/THEME/template/catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml*** .

2) Comment out the below code:

```
 <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '_clone') ?
```

> 